# Horizontally Center Align Animated Inline-Block with a fixed position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally center align a inline-block element that also has a fixed position. This is because this element is also being animation via transform translation. Current attempt looks like this:

```
.cd-nav-trigger {
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
}

.cd-nav-trigger {
bottom: 7%;
left: 48.25%;
top: auto;
right: auto;
width: 44px;
height: 44px;    
z-index: 5;
/* image replacement */
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
}


.cd-overlay-nav, .cd-overlay-content {
/* containers of the 2 main rounded backgrounds - these containers are used to position the rounded bgs behind the menu icon */
position: fixed;
bottom: 7%;
left: 48.25%;
height: 4px;
width: 4px;
-webkit-transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px);
-moz-transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px);
-ms-transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px);
-o-transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px);
transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px);
}
```

HTML implementation is this:

```
</div> <!-- cd-overlay-content -->

<a href="#0" class="cd-nav-trigger">Menu<span class="cd-icon"></span></a>

</div>
```

The `left` property is not allowing me to correctly align the element, even when set to 50%. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make js fiddle link?

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a negative `margin-left` (half of the `width`)

```css
.cd-nav-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: -22px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#0" class="cd-nav-trigger">Menu<span class="cd-icon"></span></a>
```